# LaTex Error message: !Missing \endcsname inserted

Tags: errors

I'm getting this error message when compliling my .tex file:

> ! Missing \endcsname inserted.
>   
>                     \relax
>   l.34 ...

Preamble of my code is following:

```
\documentclass [a4paper,11pt,twocolumn] {article}
\usepackage[left=2cm,text={17cm, 24cm},top=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage[IL2]{fontenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{url}

\providecommand{\uv}[1]{\quotedblbase #1\textquotedblleft}
```

Could anyone please tell me, what might cause this error?

Here's my code, but I'm not really sure, where is the problem. (I deleted the text in brackets that belongs to title page, just for the sake of anonymity)

```
\begin{document}

\author{}
\title{}
\date{}
\maketitle

\section{Hladká sazba}
Hladká sazba je sazba z~jednoho stupně, druhu a~řezu písma sázená na stanovenou šířku odstavce. Skládá se z odstavců, které obvykle začínají zarážkou, ale mo\-hou být sázeny i~bez zarážky\,--\,rozhodující je celková grafická úprava. Odstavce jsou ukončeny východovou řádkou. Věty nesmějí začínat číslicí.
\par
Barevné zvýraznění, podtrhávání slov či různé ve\-likosti písma vybraných slov se zde také nepoužívá. Hladká sazba je určena především pro delší texty, jako je například beletrie. Porušení konzistence sazby působí v~textu rušivě a~unavuje čtenářův zrak.

\section{Smíšená sazba} %\label{smisena}
Smíšená sazba má o~něco volnější pravidla, jak hladká sazba. Nejčastěji se klasická hladká sazba doplňuje o~další řezy písma pro zvýraznění důležitých pojmů. Existuje \uv{pravidlo}:

\begin{quotation}
\textsc{Čím více druhů, řezů, veli\-kostí, barev písma a~jiných efektů použijeme, tím profesionálněji bude dokument vypadat. Čtenář tím bude vždy nadšen!}
\end{quotation}

Tímto pravidlem se \underline{nikdy} nesmíte řídit. Příliš časté zvýrazňování textových elementů a~změny \Alph{\huge{v}\LARGE{e}\Large{l}\large{i}\normalsize{k}\small{o}\footnotesize{s}\scriptsize{t}\tiny{i}} \normalsize{písma} {\large jsou} {\Large známkou} {\LARGE \bfseries amatérismu} autora a~působí \emph{\bfseries velmi\/rušivě}. Dobře navržený dokument nemá obsahovat více než 4 řezy či druhy písma. \texttt{Dobře navržený dokument je decentní, ne chaotický.}
\par
Důležitým znakem správně vysázeného dokumentu je konzistentní používání různých druhů zvýraznění. To například může znamenat, že \textbf{tučný řez} písma bude vyhrazen pouze pro klíčová slova, \emph{skloněný řez} pouze pro doposud neznámé pojmy a~nebude se to míchat. Skloněný řez nepůsobí tak rušivě a~používá se častěji. V~{\LaTeX}u jej sázíme raději příkazem \verb|\emph{text}| než \verb|\textit{text}|.
\par
Smíšená sazba se nejčastěji používá pro sazbu vědeckých článků a~technických zpráv. U~delších dokumentů vědeckého či technického charakteru je zvykem upozornit čtenáře na význam různých typů zvýraznění v~úvodní kapitole.

\section{České odlišnosti}
Česká sazba se oproti okolnímu světu v~některých aspektech mírně liší. Jednou z~odlišností je sazba uvozovek. Uvozovky se v~češtině používají převážně pro zobrazení přímé řeči. V~menší míře se používají také pro zvýraznění přezdívek a~ironie. V~češtině se používá tento \uv{typ uvozovek} namísto anglických \textquotedblleft{uvozovek}".
\par
Ve smíšené sazbě se řez uvozovek řídí řezem prvního uvozovaného slova. Pokud je uvozována celá věta, sází se koncová tečka před uvozovku, pokud se uvozuje slovo nebo část věty, sází se tečka za uvozovku.
\par
Druhou odlišností je pravidlo pro sázení konců řádků. V~české sazbě by řádek neměl končit osamocenou jednopísmennou předložkou nebo spojkou (spojkou \uv{a} končit může při sazbě do 25 liter). Abychom {\LaTeX}u zabránili v~sázení osamocených předložek, vkládáme mezi předložku a~slovo nezlomitelnou mezeru znakem \verb|~| (vlnka, tilda). Pro automatické doplnění vlnek slouží volně šiřitelný program \emph{vlna} od pana Olšáka\footnote{Viz \url{ftp://math.feld.cvut.cz/pub/olsak/vlna/}.}.

\end{document}
```

Could anyone please tell me, what might cause this error?

Comment: You code compiles file, and [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).  However, it would be helpful if you turned your code into a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that reproduces the problem.

While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! A quick hint: If you indent lines of LaTeX code by four spaces, they will be pretty-printed automatically.

Comment: Please post a complete small document that generates that error. Posting error free code doesn't help up to help you work out the error.

Comment: I've just added the complete document, hope it helps you in working out the error.

Comment: What's the use of `\Alph`? It's mean to take a counter as an argument, yet you pass it a bunch of textual/string content. Unrelated is also your incorrect use of font switches within the `\Alph` argument. Use `{\Large X}` instead of `\Large{X}`...

Comment: Note that the error message does accurately show where your error was. `! Missing \endcsname inserted. \relax l.34 ...` means teh error is on line 34 (I get l.30 but oresumably you have some white space between the two fragments of document that you posted accounting for the 4 lines difference)

Comment: removing the text of the example leaves a later reader without the information to make sense of the answers.  it would be helpful if you restore at least enough to show where the error occurred.

Comment: My comment refers only to aesthetics of your source of the document, no to the problem itself. Why are you using `\par` commands between paragraphs instead of empty lines? Empty lines are more transparent when reading and more easy during writing.

Answer (score 7):

The problem comes from the paragraph that comes just after the quotation environment and begins with `Tímto pravidlem`. More precisely the use of `\Alph`: it's a LaTeX command that formats a counter display, so its argument has to be a counter. I don't understand what was expected with this command.

Comment: The usage around that part should probably resemble `{\huge v}{\LARGE e}{\Large l}{\large i}{\normalsize k}{\small o}{\footnotesize s}{\scriptsize t}{\tiny i}`.

Answer (score 6):

For fun, the problematic part translated to English (based on Google Translate):

```
\documentclass [a4paper,11pt,twocolumn] {article}

\begin{document}
  \noindent
  Too frequent \underline{highlighting} of text elements and
  {\huge c}{\LARGE h}{\Large a}{\normalsize n}{\small g}%
  {\footnotesize i}{\scriptsize n}{\tiny g}
  {\tiny the}
  {\scriptsize font}
  {\footnotesize size}
  {\small is}
  {\normalsize a}
  {\large sign}
  {\Large of}
  {\LARGE \bfseries amateurism}.
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The real problem `\Alph` expecting a counter name is already covered by comments and answer.